# How can I wait for a timer to finished before I execute next line of code without putting the thread to sleep?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to have a timed execution of some code in my application. I am creating multiple threads in my application, and I am trying to get them to execute code at the same time.

I am wondering if there is a way to make my thread wait until my timer has finished before it continues on with the next bit of code without putting it to sleep? Currently I am doing just that but surely there is another way. Can anyone offer some assistance?

```
        System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = (2000);
        _timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
                              {
                                  //code to execute
            _timer.Enabled = false;
        };
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //code to invoke my finished delegate
```

Comment: Is this Winforms and are you worried about the UI thread (or is that taken care of)?

Comment: usual way to do this is to place the @code to invoke my finished delegate@ in a separate method, and call that method inside the timer delegate instead. Then if you need to call another piece of code from that method, create a new timer and place that block into it's own method as well.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, if it's the UI thread, it could go back to running the message pump and if it's a thread pool thread, it could be released back into the pool to execute a different task.  These two cases are what the `await Task.Delay` approaches allow.

Comment: @DanBryant - Both of those are likely to result in the thread sleeping... at least until another event occurs...

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** for a **cleaner asynchronous approach**:

```
Task.Run(async delegate 
{ 
   await Task.Delay(2000); 
   //do stuff here
});
```

[`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) creates asynchronous operations and (mostly) abstracts away the threading model. When you're inside a routine marked `async`, the `await` keyword means "wait for this to finish and then run". In the example above, this is all happening outside your executing thread.

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to use a `Timer`, just use [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature, that will not block your `UI` Thread

```
private async void SomeMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000); // wait two seconds asynchronously
    // your code goes here
    // this code will be executed after two seconds
}
```

Comment: What about the code suggests to you that they are using a version of .NET that supports async/await?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to have a timed execution of some code in my application. I am creating multiple threads in my application, and I am trying to get them to execute code at the same time.

One way to do it (based on your multiple threads comment) is to use the [CountDownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

```
 using (var mySignal = new CountDownEvent(doWorks.Count))
 {
    foreach (var doWork in doWorks)
    {
      // Start Threads example
      Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        // do work

        // signal this thread done
        mySignal.Signal();
      }
    }

    // wait for all threads
    mySignal.Wait();

    // All threads are done.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you absolutely must do it this way, you could use [EventWaitHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)

As mentioned, you're likely better off using another implementation such as those mentioned.