# Line not being called after timer on unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I used the best solution from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373036/how-can-i-wait-for-a-timer-to-finished-before-i-execute-next-line-of-code-withou) And it's not running the line of code I set up to run after 2 seconds.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class ClickingBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            gameObject.transform.localScale += new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 
            Task.Run(async delegate 
            { 
                await Task.Delay(2000); 
                gameObject.transform.localScale += new Vector3(-1, -1, -1); // line is not being called
   
            });
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: as a quick view, it doesnt look like that compiled..

Comment: I think in Unity you are supposed to use `yield new WaitForSeconds(2000)` or something like that, go read the Unity docs.

Comment: @DavidG that would be in a coroutine.. await works, but I was confident you needed to async the method... and doing it in update could have bad effects, plus, controlling something off the mainthread can also go bad..

Comment: the main issue is that `Task.Run` will most probably run on a different thread and most of the Unity API is only allowed to be used on the Unity main thread! [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) are on of many ways to ensure that, you could also use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) in your case or a simple `float` timer in Update

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to make a delay in your cod line. In unity, we use IEnumerator for this. Here is an example that makes 2 seconds delay:

```
void Start()
{
    //Start the coroutine we define below named ExampleCoroutine.
    StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine());
}

IEnumerator ExampleCoroutine()
{
    //yield on a new YieldInstruction that waits for 2 seconds.
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

you can use `StartCoroutine()` method where you need it in your code.

Comment: Yep, tho, it might help to include a link to the official docs that says this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html